# Type error when trying to use list with QTableView

Tags: python, user-interface, pyside

I'm trying to represent objects of a class as a table in a QMainWindow, but for some reason, QTableView isn't accepting the list, even though in the examples I saw that used it, they used a list. The code for the window is this:

```py
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QWidget, QMainWindow, QPushButton, QTableView, QHBoxLayout
class FeedexWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, data):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle(f"FeeDex {__version__}")
        save_button = QPushButton("Save")
        save_button.clicked.connect(self.click_print)

        subs_table = QTableView(data)


        parent_layout = QHBoxLayout()
        parent_layout.addWidget(subs_table)
        parent_layout.addWidget(save_button)

        main_widget = QWidget()
        main_widget.setLayout(parent_layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(main_widget)
```

And the code for the code execution is this:

```py
from lib.__init__ import __version__
from lib.classes import *
from proto_gui_logic import *
import sys
from datetime import datetime as dt
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication

settings = Settings()
for series, info in settings.subs.items():
    try:
        Mangas(series, info["relationships"][1]["id"], info["attributes"]["chapter"], info["attributes"]["title"], info["id"], info["attributes"]["publishAt"], info["favGroup"])
    except KeyError:
        Mangas(series, info["relationships"][1]["id"], info["attributes"]["chapter"], info["attributes"]["title"], info["id"], info["attributes"]["publishAt"])

data = []
for manga in Mangas.registry_:
    data.append([manga.series_title, f"Ch. No {manga.ch_no} - {manga.ch_title}", dt.strptime(manga.latest_date, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z')])

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = FeedexWindow(data)
window.show()
app.exec()
```

For reference, this is part of what data looks like after that loop:

```py
[['Usuzumi no Hate', 'Ch. No 9 - Library', '2023-03-02T08:14:40+00:00']]
```

The `settings` instance of the `Settings()` class is reading from a json, if you need to know. Trying to do this, gives the following error:

```bash
TypeError: 'PySide6.QtWidgets.QTableView.__init__' called with wrong argument types:
  PySide6.QtWidgets.QTableView.__init__(list)
Supported signatures:
  PySide6.QtWidgets.QTableView.__init__(Optional[PySide6.QtWidgets.QWidget] = None)
```

Comment: I don't know what examples you're referring to, but QTableView does ***not*** accept a list as argument in its constructor. What you probably saw was a custom subclass that did accept those arguments and implemented its behavior accordingly. Most importantly, QTableView is a *view*, and it requires a *model* that will be then applied to the view with `view.setModel(model)`. Either use QStandardItemModel and fill it with items based on your data, or implement a QAbstractTableModel subclass; eventually, use QTableWidget, which has its own internal model (but you still need to fill it).

Comment: You're welcome. I suggest you to take your time and read the documentation about [Qt Model/View programming](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html).

Comment: I actually was reading the documentation, but I was having trouble making sense of this part, so thank you a whole lot for the help